# CoreData count records of TWICE related entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, relation

I have three Entities: Institution, Course, Student
An Institution can have many Courses, a Course can have only one Institution (1 - many)
A Course can have many Students, a Student can join many Courses (many - many).

Counting the Courses of an Institution is very simple, with its relation named "course":

```
int numberCourses = institution.course.count;
```

MY QUESTION:

How am I able to count the number of Students in an Institution? 
In Entity Course I have the relation "student" to Entity Student. How can I access from **Institution thru Course to Student?**

Note: A Student can be member in many courses and with that it's possible for him to be member of many Institutions.

Say it simple and analog to the code line above, I want this:

> institution -> **ALL courses** -> student.count

Thank you for help!!
C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different solutions. You can get the set of all students of the institution and 
count them:

```
NSSet *students = [institution valueForKeyPath:@"courses.students"];
NSUInteger numberOfStudents = [students count];
```

(I have used the plural form for to-many relationships which I find more intuitive.)

Or you build a fetch request for the students related to the institution:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Student"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY courses.institution == %@", institution];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSUInteger numberOfStudents = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The second solution has the advantage that the *Student* objects and the intermediate *Course* objects are not loaded into memory. Counting the number of objects is done
on the SQLite level.

Comment: Hey Man!!!! Thank you so much. I always tried to look from the institution-side. Very simple, worked on first try! Perfect! I took the second solution.